# Duplicate Project Bundle entity reference on Related Tab in Product Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

Product Entity Related Tab shows Product Bundle twice (Refer Screenshot), even if the Form Navigation has a single Navigation specified for Product Bundle(Refer Screenshot). This scenario works fine in Classic Interface and shows Product Bundle only once..!

[image]
[image]
Tried Updating the Product Association relationship property 'Navigation Pane Item for Primary Entity' option to 'Don't Display' still the Product Bundle was visible twice..! Changing it to show Custom Label, didn't do any magic either.

Further, On removal of Product Bundle Navigation from Product Form and  re- adding it back and publishing it.. doesn't show even a single product Bundle in Related Tabs in Product Entity. (refer Screenshot) (Note - Works fine in Classic Interface)

[image]

Please let me know, if there is any solution for the same.

Comment: I believe the same case with “Product Requests” too.. I guess some buggy UCI behavior..